# EOS M focal length conversion to cropped frame and full frame camera

Tags: canon, focal-length, lens-adapter, canon-m

I am thinking about EOS M .. it looks appealing to me ... especially for Hiking .. the thing i want to know is if I use my 18-55mm Canon lens (that normally come with 550D, 600D series) on EOS M with EF adaptor, will i get equivalent focal length with 18-55mm STM IS lens that comes as a package with EOS M.

When I mean equivalent focal length, the angle (view) should be same at both e.g. 18mm with both lens.

And how about the view at e.g. 18mm on cropped frame camera can be compared with 18mm on EOS M. Would it be the same ? I basically understand about full frame and cropped frame (1.6x) conversion. How about EOS M? what rules apply?

Many Thanks,

L

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's 1.6 for EOS M - it is based on sensor size and EF adaptor makes EF lenses work the same as for DSLR APS-C cameras. Even though EF M lenses are mounted closer to sensor, they are still marked standard way (with regard to correctly estimate field of depth) so it finally comes to sensor size alone.